# Trying to get rid of trailing spaces in python regex

Tags: python, regex, trim

I have a CSV that I am working with in Python REGEX. I need to extract values in the final field of the CSV, but I am having trouble with it in regex101.com (fantastic page, by the way).

A couple of example rows:

```
,11/12/2017,00-87-67 34849444,-27.00,ITEMRECEIVED,H2G2                   929613292012071217 REF
,02/01/2018,00-87-68 58493922,-1110.79,ITEMSENT,MIL P01  WOOLLIES     9221234545         DEG
```

I need to capture the final "MEMO" field on the end with this regex:

```
(?:[^\,]*\,){5}(?P<CompanyName>[^\s].*)\s{4,19}(?P<Reference>\S{1,18})\s{1,11}(?P<Type>\w{3})
```

What I am getting is:

```
CompanyName           Reference             Type
-----------           -----------           ----
'H2G2               ' '929613292012071217'  'REF'
'MIL P01  WOOLLIES  ' '9221234545'          'DEG'
```

It doesn't seem much, but how can I get the regex to trim the trailing spaces in the CompanyName, so that I get the following instead, please?

```
CompanyName         Reference             Type
-----------         -----------           ----
'H2G2'              '929613292012071217'  'REF'
'MIL P01  WOOLLIES' '9221234545'          'DEG'
```

Thanks in advance,

QuietLeni

Comment: the lines start with a comma?

Comment: I would advise using the standard library [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) instead of using regexes – it will be better at avoiding these kinds of problems.

Comment: Sorry, that is not available to me in this environment. I am using a tool that uses Python, but does not expose other libraries.

Comment: Not all of the lines start with a comma. One or two have a number before the comma, which is why I find all of the commas first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your regex to:

```
(?:[^\,]*\,){5}(?P<CompanyName>[^\s].*\S)\s{4,19}(?P<Reference>\S{1,18})\s{1,11}(?P<Type>\w{3})
```

Adding `\S` basically means that after the last non-whitespace character there have to be no more whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

One approach might be using a lookahead to "short-circuit" a wildcard (non-greedy), like so:

```
(?P<CompanyName>.*?)(?=\s+\d)
```

whole pattern:

```
(?:[^\,]*\,){5}(?P<CompanyName>.*?)(?=\s+\d)\s*(?P<Reference>\S{1,18})\s{1,11}(?P<Type>\w{3})
```

(Depends on the possibilities inherent in your data of course, here I'm assuming that the company name can't end with an isolated number)

https://regex101.com/r/reT66g/1/

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something, just adding a question mark to this thing should do it `(?P<CompanyName>[^\s].*)` (making the quantifier non-greedy)

e.g. `(?P<CompanyName>[^\s].*)` -> `(?P<CompanyName>[^\s].*?)`

Answer (score 0):

Just to put my two cents in - you could use

```
,
(?P<CompanyName>\b(?:(?!\d{3,})[A-Z\d ])+\b)\s+
(?P<Reference>\b\d{1,18}\b)\s+
(?P<Type>[A-Z]+)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/3HmGnx/1/).